# universal-cookie make private routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

So I have my app

```
import Header from './core/Header'; 
import Home from './core/pages/Home'; 
import MaterialTableDemo from './core/pages/Dashboard';
import BuildAd from './core/pages/BuildAd';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          
        <Switch>
          
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>  
          <Container disableGutters={true} maxWidth="xl">
       
          <Header/>    
          <Route exact path="/inde" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={MaterialTableDemo} />
          <Route exact path="/build-ad" component={BuildAd} />
          </Container>

        </Switch>
       
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>  
  );
}
```

I want to make the following routes (have to have a cookie to access)

```
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={MaterialTableDemo} />
          <Route exact path="/build-ad" component={BuildAd} />
```

with the comment below. I was kinda understand but the issue is how do i check the cookie in this const? I tried.

```
const cookiea = cookies.get('access_key');

const fakeAuth = {
  if(cookiea)
    isAuthenticated: true,
  
  authenticate(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};
```

but that makes an error

```
 Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

  69 | const fakeAuth = {
  70 |   if(cookiea)
> 71 |     isAuthenticated: true,
     |     ^
  72 |   
  73 |   authenticate(cb) {
  74 |     fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
```

Comment: Check https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow for Private Routes.

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks, its quite interesting I was hoping Route would of had an inbuilt function that allows it to check if cookies exisits

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks, I cant figure out how I get the the 

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

to check cookies.get("access_key")

Comment: You can ignore the `fakeAuth`, and simply create a function `isAuthenticated` which returns `true` when the user is logged in and `false` otherwise. "How to know if user is logged in or not?" depends on the way you plan to implement the "Authentication" (cookie or localstorage etc.).

Comment: @AjeetShah so say there is a cookie on a computer - we send that cookie off to our server to be checked if true we let in if not true we don't

Comment: The error is saying the code is expecting either the `if` expression to have a code block, i.e. `if (...) { ...}`, or that `isAuthenticated: true` should be in an object, i.e. `{ isAuthenticated: true }` or both, but it is rather unclear what you are trying to do as your `fakeAuth` isn't a valid object or function block either.

Comment: It seems like your question is not "How to create Private Route", but "How to manage authentication in react", so you can find many tutorials on that. You can see [this](https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e), they provided full repo code too.